# javascript check key is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, ctrl

I want to create code which invoked when I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.

This is my code:

```
var ready = true;
$("document").ready(function(){
     readShift()
 });
 function readShift(){
    if (ready){
        $(window).keydown(function (e){
            if (e.ctrlKey){
                alert("clicked");
            }
        });
    }
    readShift();
}
```

After I click the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, the alert loop forever although after that I am not click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

What I need is the alert invoked just when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Comment: You have a problem with infinite recursive calls in the page - you should see an error like *Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded* in your console

Comment: why are you calling `readShift` inside `readShift`?

Comment: oh, i missunderstand about how JS work, i think i should looping forever in order to my code work forever. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function calls itself recursively at the second to last line

```
function readShift(){
    ...
    readShift();
}
```

This means that even though the method finishes, it will be invoked over and over again.

Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx) on recusrion to understand what happenes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not useful:

```
if (ready){
```

The document is already ready because you are calling within a jQuery.ready.

It is going through an infinite loop because you are calling     readShift(); recursively.
This is the correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     readShift()
 });
 function readShift(){
        $(window).keydown(function (e){console.log("ciao");
            if (e.ctrlKey){
                alert("clicked");
            }
        });

}
```

**EDIT**: I also forgot to mention that $("document") is not getting any result, you should use $(document). jQuery makes a "query" inside the DOM. Unless there is a "document" tag in the DOM, $("document") is not finding anything

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(window).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey){
            alert("clicked");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call readShift() there is another readShift() inside of the function.

If you call this function, there are plenty of listeners on you keydown event. So when you click it, there are hundrets of alerts, because hundrets of listeners are triggered.

Remove readShift() from the function to get it work.